# PostgreSQL on Elastic Beanstalk (Amazon Linux 2)

Tags: linux, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, yum

With former generation of Amazon Linux, all I needed to do is add the following in .ebextensions in order to use PostgreSQL:

```
packages:
    yum:
        postgresql93-devel: []
```

Now when I deploy on EB with the following platform:
Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.0

I get the following error on deployment:

```
[ERROR] Error occurred during build: Yum does not have postgresql93-devel available for installation
```

Therefore it is impossible to deploy as I need to connect to a PostgreSQL database in RDS.

What config in .ebextensions do I need to do?

Comment: Amazon Linux 2 moved some packages to `amazon-linux-extras`. That could be one of the things

Comment: Amazon Linux 1 did not have `amazon-linux-extras`.  Its new to AL2.  Here's a good summary: https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/faqs/#Amazon_Linux_Extras

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The following works:

```
packages:
    yum:
        amazon-linux-extras: []

commands:
    01_postgres_activate:
        command: sudo amazon-linux-extras enable postgresql10
    02_postgres_install:
        command: sudo yum install -y postgresql-devel
```

Comment: <3 I love you. literally the only thing that does this. I used AL2. I tried putting what you have here as `02_postgres_install` in a config file that would get executed using the packages configuration key (what you did for amazon-linux-extras) and it didn't work. had to be executed as a command. Thank you!!

Comment: What is 10 in postgresql10? Is it the RDS's postgres version? Should I state postgresql12 instead of postgresql10 if the postgres version in my RDS is 12.5?

Comment: The 10 is the postgres version as found in the amazon-linux-extras list. They don't have a v12 as of this time.

Comment: Documentation for AWS  [install a software package from the Extras Library](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-install-extras-library-software/)

Answer (score 3):

`postgresql93-devel` is pretty old.  [The yum PostgreSQL repository](https://yum.postgresql.org/) starts at 9.5.  Depending on your needs you may want to upgrade to at least 9.5.  PostgreSQL 12 is the latest production release.

**EDIT**

As to the comment @jordanm made - that's correct, the AWS Linux 2 environment does have PostgreSQL 9.2.24 available.  If you're ok with that version then you can just install `postgresql-devel`.  Change your `.ebextensions` to just run:

```
packages:
    yum:
        postgresql-devel: []
```

This will install the `devel` package for 9.2.24.

If you'd like something a bit newer, it's apparently a bunch harder.  I was unable to get this to work for the `devel` package.  If you change your `.ebextensions` to contain something like (not tested!):

```
container_commands:
    command: 'amazon-linux-extras install -y postgresql9.6'
```

Then you'll get PostgreSQL 9.6 but it does not appear to have the `devel` package available.

It doesn't look possible to use the RPM's from https://yum.postgresql.org/ as AWS Linux 2 is not supported.  Trying CentOS or RHEL gives an error.

Is 9.2 usable for your environment?

Comment: I tried with:         postgresql11-devel: []
but also failing

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same issues

Answer (score 1):

Something that helped me with Amazon Linus 1, is the fact that I didn't need to install Postgres at all when plugging in a RDS service and specifying Postgres as the driver. It's just a thought for people having this problem. But maybe just try to not explicitly install Postgres.

I haven't validated which version will be installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration works fine with the ElasticBeanstalk environment (Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux). After this, I was able to install psycopg2 with requirements.txt

```
packages:
    yum:
        libicu-devel: []

commands:
    01_postgres_libs:
        command: rpm -ivh --force https://yum.postgresql.org/10/redhat/rhel-6.9-x86_64/postgresql10-libs-10.7-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
    02_postgres_install:
        command: rpm -ivh --force https://yum.postgresql.org/10/redhat/rhel-6.9-x86_64/postgresql10-10.7-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
    03_symink_pg_config:
        command: sudo ln -sf /usr/pgsql-10/bin/pg_config /usr/bin/pg_config
    04_postgres_devel:
        command: sudo rpm -ivh --force https://yum.postgresql.org/10/redhat/rhel-6.9-x86_64/postgresql10-devel-10.7-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
```